# Can maven report if there are newer versions of a dependency automatically?

Tags: maven, maven-3

Is there a maven command that can analyze a given pom.xml and report if there are newer versions of  plugins or dependencies.

For example suppose that the pom.xml depends on hibernate 4.1.6 and hibernate 4.1.7 is released is there a command that can analyze the pom.xml and print out something along the lines, you are using hibernate 4.1.6 and the latest version is 4.1.7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [Versions Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/) goals version-display-* and versions-use-*